# Is there a way to find predicted R-squared using PROC REG in SAS?

Tags: sas, statistics

I am looking to have SAS calculated the predicted R-squared value using PROC REG.

Answer (score 0):

You mean the R-Square? It's very easy to get.

```
ods output FitStatistics = FitStatistics;
proc reg data = sashelp.class;
    model height = age;
quit;
ods output close;
```

The R-Square is located at data set `FitStatistics`.

Comment: It shows R-squared already, but I want the R-squared predicted value (I am doing a MLR with indicator variables).